# How to mimic SMPP connection

Tags: testing, production-environment, kannel

I have a situation. My application is sending multiple SMSes to end client this number varies from 50000 to 100000 SMSes at any point of time. To achieve this functionality i am using Kannel as sms sender interface.

So My solution is complete. But only in development environment! Before going to be in production I supposed to do a testing of this solution environment.

Is there any suggestion to created a testing environment?

To give more input to my environment; kannel is using an smpp connection to deliver messages to end client. So, I think i need to mimic some smpp server for kannel.

Answer (score 1):

SMPPSIM from [www.seleniumsoftware.com](http://www.seleniumsoftware.com/)

Also try SCTT and Logica SMSCSim

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy setting up a Java envrionment, Logica have an open-source simulator application that works quite well.

http://opensmpp.logica.com/CommonPart/Download/download2.html#simulator

I've used it to push through quite a lot (in the order of several million) sms in test, so it's quite robust. I've also got a version compiled using .Net (J#) that /seems/ to work OK; give me a shout if you want to try that out.

Comment: Hi Paul, I am very exited about the environment. I have read through the document provided on logica site. But it does not seems helpful. 

Please help me to setup my test environment.

Comment: Hi Vijay.

The logica documentation is a little unclear :-)

I've a project built from source that I can send you if you let me have your email address. There's a small batch file in there that will run the simulator. If I send you that and you need anything else, please let me know.

Comment: Hey Paul, I would very much like to receive your revisions to the Logica sources. What I want to do is to stress test a Kannel I've configured with a backing HTTP service. Email is majab10@hotmail.com. Many thanks.